# ASP.NET: Errors in autogenerated .Designer.cs file for Model

Tags: asp.net

I'm new to ASP.NET and having a problem with a tutorial.

I've created a new MVC4 Project in VS2012 Express for Web.
And I've added a SQL Database with 1 Table "Persons" and filled it with some random testdata:

```
Id        int (primary key, is identity=true)
name      varchar(50)
birthdate date 


adam  01.01.2001
berta 02.02.2002
```

As a Model I've used ADO.NET Entity Data Model, named it "PersonsModel.edmx"
and used the Personsdatabase for it.

To see the PersonsModel.Designer.cs file, I activated "Codegeneration Status" to "Standard". Refreshed and clicked on the PersonsModel.Designer.cs file.
But in this file I've errors... So I wanted to use something like this in my controller:

HomeController.cs:

```
PersonsEntities1 db = new PersonsEntities();

db.person...
```

but it doesn't work, and I think(?) it's because of the errors in the .Designer.cs file.

PersonsModel.Designer.cs: e.g.:

```
public PersonsEntities1() : base("name=PersonsEntities1", "PersonsEntities1")
{
        this.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
        OnContextCreated();
}
```

errors in the base: ... line
and in ContextOptions.
Unfortunately I've no english VS, but it says something like:

> The best accordance für the overloaded System.Data.Entity.DbContext(string, System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbCompiledModel)-Method has some invalid arguments
>
> And no definition found for "ContextOptions", there is no method "ContextOptions" which accepts "MvcApplication7.Models.PersonsEntities1" as a first argument.

I'm a bit confused, because I did it like in the tutorial explained.

Comment: In your second code snippet, where you're assigning a value of type `PersonsEntities` to a variable of type `PersonsEntities1`, are the different types a typo?

Comment: yes, this is a typo! When i want to call PersonsEntities db = new PersonsEntities(); -> new PersonsEntities(); is underlined and it says "This call doesn't distinguish between following methods and properties: "MvcApplication7.Models.PersonEntities2.PersonEntities2()" and "MvcApplication7.Models.PersonEntities2.PersonEntities2()"" (same)

Comment: Do you know what version of Entity Framework you're using?

Comment: It sounds to me as if you have multiple generated files with similar code.  (I note that you started with PersonEntities and are now up to PersonEntities2.)  If you've been deleting and then re-creating files, things can get messed up quickly.  It might be worth starting a whole new project. :(

Comment: didn't find any hint for the version... it says only ADO.NET Entity Data Model :) yah I know thats a bit messy now... I've already created some new projects

Comment: Can you provide a link to the tutorial?

Comment: it's a video tutorial called: "video2brain asp.net mvc". I can see in this video, that there is no code marked as wrong (red underlined)... in the tutors code. As it is in my Designer file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the problem was VS2012. It all works with VS2010.

I've downloaded the installer again from asp.net/mvc and added Visual Web Developer 2010 Express. After installation of VS2010 and all dependencies I tried the tutorial again and all works fine now. No wrong code in the .Designer.cs file :).

Thanks a lot Ann L. for your support. Your hint (wrong version of Entity Framework installed) prompt me to try another VS version.

In addition I've to say: I also tried VS2012 Ultimate (complete DVD version) but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

I think this code is in error:

```
base("name=PersonsEntities1", "PersonsEntities1")
```

There is no constructor that takes two strings.  Your second argument is supposed to be of type `DbCompiledModel`.  (See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679522%28v=vs.103%29.aspx).)

Now, I don't know why your designer would produce code that can't compile, so I'm wondering whether you have the wrong version of Entity Framework installed.

Comment: wow that was fast I've already created several new projects and still the same problem... do you think reinstalling VS could help?

Comment: Did you install VS by itself or did you install any updates (like for MVC or EF) before you installed VS?

Comment: I installed VS from this site (http://www.asp.net/mvc) and nothing else before. Standard installation. I'll try reinstalling it somehow :).

Comment: Might conceivably be a naming conflict.  Did you name anything else "PersonEntities", or use it in a namespace?

Comment: no don't think so. It's a new project, just added the database and model.

Comment: I also noticed that you said you named the model `PersonsModel`, but you're using `PersonsEntities` a lot.  Are you using both names?

Comment: yes the Model is named PersonsModel and in the PersonsModel.Designer.cs it is PersonsEntities